# CruiseControl.NET: How to access modifications in MSBuild task?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'd like to do some action based on modified files. I have such project configuration

```
<project name="MyProject">
  <sourcecontrol type="vsts" autoGetSource="true">
  ...
  </sourcecontrol>
  <tasks>
    <msbuild>
    ...
    </msbuild>
  </tasks>
```

Is there any way how to put or access the modifications comes from source control in that configured MSBuild task? I cannot see any integration property for this, but I can see modifications in CCNET build log

```
<cruisecontrol project="MyProject">
  <request source="ScheduledTrunk" buildCondition="ForceBuild">...</request>
  <modifications>
    <modification type="merge">
      <filename>MyFile.cs</filename>
      <project>$/MyProject/Trunk/Source/</project>
      <date>2010-02-23 02:27:40</date>
      <user>domain\user</user>
      <comment>Some comment</comment>
      <changeNumber>79367</changeNumber>
      <version>79367</version>
    </modification>
  </modifications>
  <integrationProperties>
  ...
  </integrationProperties>
  <build date="..." buildtime="..." buildcondition="...">
  <msbuild
    startTime="02/23/2010 11:55:52"
    elapsedTime="00:00:51" success="true"
  >
  ...
  </msbuild>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Thanks for suggestion!

BTW do you know why the common [CCNet documentation](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) pages are down for several days already? And what is the primary discussion forum for CCNET?

Comment: +1 for the question about the documentation pages. I was wondering about this as well.

Comment: Under normal circumstances the availability of CCNET documentation is bad, but this time it is really, really bad. Try http://groups.google.de/group/ccnet-user as discussion forum.

Comment: ... and presto magic CCNET doc is online again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [Mofification Writer Task](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Modification+Writer+Task). This tasks writes modification details to an XML file, which can easily be evaluated from an MSBuild task.